# How to update an existing card in Subscriptions?

Tags: devdemon, subscriptions

I'm using DevDemon's Subscriptions to maintain a subscription service for a client site.

I see tags for adding cards and deleting cards, but I don't see anything for updating an existing card on an existing subscription?

In their docs, the allude to it:

http://www.devdemon.com/documentation/tag/subs-cards/

```
<a href="{path="subs/cards_edit/&#123;subs:hash&#125;"}">Edit</a>
```

...but there is no cards_edit template in their examples, and I see no tags for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the four different example templates included?

They are: cards.html, cards_add.html, cards_delete.html, cards_add_stripe.html. With cards add there is an optional parameter delete_cards="yes" that will remove the other card if you wish to only have one card and not make the customer delete it first. This way they can never not have a card.

Comment: Also, make sure you download Subscription 1.5.3 and REUPLOAD the templates. As they do not install with updater. You have to install them and resync again. The templates have come a long way since 1.0.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I did upload the templates manually... so what you're saying is there is no option to edit an existing card, rather only to add a new card (and optionally delete an old one)?

Comment: Yes that is how it works. A new token must be generated.